# llamar una función dentro de condicional Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de realizar este código pero no me funciona, no sé si es que no se puede, o si lo estoy haciendo mal.
Defino una función, luego le pido al usuario oprimir una tecla y por medio de un `if` reviso que se halla presionado la tecla para visualizar resultado pero no me funciona.

```
def suma():
res = 5 + 3
print (res)
print("oprimir una tecla")
tecla = input()
int (tecla)
if tecla == 1:
suma()
```

Comment: `int(tecla)` convierte a entero, pero no usas el resultado para nada. Por tanto, `tecla` sigue conteniendo un caracter, no un valor entero.

Answer (score 1):

Varias cosas:

1. Python requiere resperat la identación, deberías adentrar las líneas `res=5+3` y `suma()`
2. El condicional `==1` implica que sólo la tecla <kbd>1</kbd> funcionará
3. `input()` pausa el programa hasta que reciba datos, si quieres esperar a cualquiera sobra el `if`
4. `input()` ofrece la capacidad de printar desde dentro de la función antes de realizar la petición de datos

**Solución a la identación**:

```
def suma():
    return (5 + 3)    
print("oprimir una tecla")    
tecla = input()
tecla = int(tecla)
if tecla == 1:
    print(suma())
```

Alternativamente, si la línea es única se puede compactar como

```
def suma(): return (5 + 3)    
print("oprimir una tecla")    
tecla = input()
tecla = int(tecla)
if tecla == 1: print(suma())
```

**Solución con texto en `input` y compactado de `int`**:
*Para que se compruebe un 1*:

```
def suma(): return (5 + 3)
tecla = input("oprimir una tecla")
if int(tecla) == 1: print(suma())
```

*Para que se espere a cualquiera*:

```
def suma(): return (5 + 3)
input("oprimir una tecla")
print(suma())
```

*Para que se espere un 1 e ignore las demás*:

```
def suma(): return (5 + 3)
tecla = 0
while int(tecla) != 1: input("oprimir una tecla")
print(suma())
```

Comment: debes tener en cuenta que input requiere pulsar dos teclas para cualquiera distinta de enter o intro ya que es al pulsar enter cuando se envia la entrada, es posible que el OP quiera que se pulse una tecla y se realice la acción para lo cual input no es lo mas apropiado

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes retornar el valor de tu función. Luego, mostrar en pantalla esta, y no olvides guardar el convertido de entero.

```
def suma(): return (5 + 3)

print("oprimir una tecla")

tecla = input()
tecla = int(tecla)
if tecla == 1: print(suma())
```